# Memory efficiency: HashMap versus Array

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I was thinking about the following situation: I want to count the occurrence of characters in a string (for example for a permutation check).

One way to do it would be to allocate an array with 256 integers (I assume that the characters are UTF-8), to fill it with zeros and then to go through the string and increment the integers on the array positions corresponding to the int value of the chars.

However, for this approach, you would have to allocate a 256 array each time, even when the analyzed string is very short (and consequently uses only a small part of the array).

An other approach would be to use a Character to Integer HashTable and to store a number for each encountered char. This way, you only would have keys for chars that actually are in the string.

As my understanding of the HashTable is rather theoretic and I do not really know how it is implemented in Java my question is: Which of the two approaches would be more memory efficient?

Edit:

During the discussion of this question (thank you for your answers everyone) I did realize that I had a very fuzzy understanding of the nature of UTF-8. After some searching, I have found [this great video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4) that I want to share, in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: I used to have an Apple II with a whopping 56K of RAM.  I also used to walk five miles to school each day, uphill both ways ... :)  Maybe back then I would have been concerned about an array of 256 integers.

Comment: I'd be rather surprised if a minimal HashMap occupies less storage than an array of 256 ints

Comment: How are the constraints of the problem defined exactly?  UTF-8 currently supports representing about 250,000 different characters.

Comment: Over a million are possible, actually assigned to a real character in a current spec is  different :)

Comment: @Affe Maybe he means Latin-1?  (Or one of the other extended ASCII character sets?)  To me, UTF-8 is an encoding, not a character set, but I've given up that fight.  Everybody is confused by it.

Comment: @Affe It's not really a 'real' problem, just something I was thinking about. So there are no hard constraints. Could you give me the advice, what string size to take when dealing with European language?

Comment: There are character sets (e.g., latin-9) that encode down to 8-bits and cover (Western) "European Languages."  In practice for most real world data even just € will have a decimal encoding of 8364.  How big an array are you willing to allocate?  The Map suddenly becomes a good deal better!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich wonder why you choose 256 as the length of your array when you assume that your String is UTF-8. In UTF-8 a character can be composed of up to 4 bytes which means quite a number of more characters than just 256.

Anyway: Using a HashTable/HashMap needs a huge memory overhead. First all your characters and integer need to be wrapped in an object (Integer/Character). And Integer consumes about 3x as much memory as an int. For arrays the difference can be even larger due to the optimizations java performs on arrays (e.g. the java stack works only in multiples of 4 byte, while in an array java allows smaller types such as a char to consume only 2 bytes).

Then the HashTable itself creates a memory overhead because it needs to maintain an array (which is usually not fully used) and linked lists to maintain all objects which generate the same hash.

Additionally access times will be dramatically faster for arrays. You save multiple method invocations (add, hashCode, iterator,...) and there exist a number of opcode in java byte code to make working with arrays more efficient.

Anyway. You question was:

> Which of the two approaches would be more memory efficient?

And it is safe to say that arrays will be more memory efficient.

However you should make absolutely sure what your requirements are. Do you need more memory efficiency? (Could be true if you process large amounts of data or you are on a slow device (mobile devices?)) How important is readability of code? How about size of code? Reuseability?

And ist 256 really the correct size?

Answer (score 3):

Without looking in the code I know that a HashMap requires, at minimum, a base object, a hashtable array, and individual objects for each hash entry.  Generally an int value would have to be stored as an Integer object so that's more objects.  Let's assume you have 30 unique characters:

- 32 bytes for the base object
- 256 bytes for a minimum-size hashtable array
- 32 bytes for each of the 30 table entries
- 16 bytes (if highly optimized) for each of 30 Integers

32 + 256 + 960 + 480 = 1728 bytes.  That's for a minimal, non-fancy implementation.

The array of 256 ints would be about 1056 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the array. From a performance aspect, you have guaranteed constant access. Better than the what a hash table can get you.

As it also only uses an constant amount of memory, I see no downside. The `HashMap` will most likely need more memory, even if you only store a few elements.

By the way, the memory footprint should not be a concern, as you will only need the data structure as long as you need it for counting. Then it will be garbage collected, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well here are the facts.

- `HashMap` uses an array for its table behind the scenes.

So if you were actually limited by finding a contiguous space in memory, HashMap's benefit is only that the array may be smaller.

- `HashMap` is generic and therefore uses objects.

Objects take up extra space. As I remember, it's typically 8 or 16 bytes minimum depending on whether it's a 32- or 64-bit system. This means the HashMap may very well not be smaller, even if the number of characters in the String is small. HashMap will require 3 extra objects for each entry: an `Entry`, a `Character` and an `Integer`. HashMap also needs to store the int for the index locally whereas the array does not.

That's beyond that there will be some extra computation using the HashMap.

I would also say space optimization is not something you should worry about here. Either way, the memory footprint is actually very small.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an array of integers that represent the int value of a char, for example the int value of f is 102 which is its ascii value

http://www.asciitable.com/

```
char c = 'f';
int x = (int)c;
```

If you know the range of char's youre dealing with then it is easier.

For each occurance of char increment the index of that char in the array by one. This approach would be slow if you have to iterate and complicated if you are to sort but wont be memory intensive.

Just be aware when you sort you lose the indexes